# Convert aspx code to razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

I am having a lot of trouble converting the following telerik aspx code to the razor view engine.  The error I am getting is : 'CS1012: Too many characters in character literal' on the first input button.

```
     <% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Customers")
    .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(c => c.CustomerID))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerID).Width(130);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyName).Width(250);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Country).Width(200);
        columns.Template(c => {
            %> <input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="updateRecord('<%= c.CustomerID %>')" /> <%
            %> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick="deleteRecord('<%= c.CustomerID %>')" /> <%
        }).Width(150);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Render();
%>
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
    @{ Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(c => c.Id))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.PartNumber).Width(100);
        columns.Template(c => {
            } <input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="updateRecord('@c.Id')" /> @{
            } <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick="deleteRecord('@c.Id')" /> @{
        }).Width(150);
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    .Filterable()
    .Render();
}
```

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put HTML in an expression like that in Razor.

Instead, use an inline template:

```
    columns.Template(@<text>
        <input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="updateRecord('@item.Id')" /> 
        <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick="deleteRecord('@item.Id')" /> 
    </text>)
```